# Chrome has timer thread?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We all know that chrome usually creates a process when creating a new tab page. Currently, I know that this process contains, js thread, render thread, worker thread that may be created, but I see that there are timing threads, in fact, these The thread is not important. The root of the problem is that the delay callback is to determine whether to execute in the event loop, or is there a thread that is timing, and once it reaches the specified time, push the callback to the js execution stack, waiting to be executed? Thank you